# Reading from a text file that has arbitrary lines and print to the console

Tags: python

In python, I am trying to figure out a way to write a function that will

1. Take text file's name as an input to read arbitrary number of lines that consists of the following: number, name, and number_2, mark where number_2 is ranged from 1 to 4 only. For each name, there are 4 different lines with different number_2 and mark in the text file.
2. Calculate the sum of the weight-adjusted mark according to the following rule

- Final_mark = ( 0.2 * mark for number_2 = 1 ) + ( 0.25 * mark for number_2 = 2)   +   ( 0.25 * mark for number_2 = 3) + ( 0.3 * mark for number_2 = 4)

3. Prints according to the following rule:

- id, name: Final_mark where id is in ascending order.

sample output: 1, james: 88.65 (next line)
2, alice: 96.15

```
                  ...
```

I am wondering what data structure would be most suitable in this case?
List or array? this is in Python.

Comment: Well, Python **doesn't** have arrays. You can use their list as an array

Comment: @sam2090 so I have to use list to read the lines. hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have array. You can use `list` which acts as arrays. I am not sure how your file is structured but you can store entire line in an `list index` and then `split` using a `delimiter`.

Small example:

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    #do processing
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) is link to `Python Input/Output` documentation

**EDIT:**
Python do have an `array` module but in your case, you cannot use them. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html),

> This module defines an object type which can compactly represent an
>   array of basic values: characters, integers, floating point numbers.
>   Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that
>   the type of objects stored in them is constrained.

Comment: Python does have arrays, they are defined in the array module.

Comment: @AlexanderBelopolsky They do but it is limited to few datatypes. I have edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

def usage():
    print "Usage: ./process_some_stuff.py <input_file>"

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    usage()
    raise ValueError("Missing input filename")

in_fn = sys.argv[1]

if os.path.isfile(in_fn):
    with open(in_fn, 'rb') as in_fh:
        line_idx = 0
        for line in in_fh:
            # do stuff here
        line_idx += 1
    in_fh.close()
else:
    usage()
    raise ValueError("Could not open input file")
```

Within the section `# do stuff here`, use the modulus operator on `line_idx` to decide how to read one of four lines into a Python dictionary containing four keys. Store that dictionary in a list. Then iterate over the list to retrieve the name and final score, which you can print out in order if the ids and names are auto-incrementing.

Comment: Could you share a pesudo sode or simple example of what would go in there? I am really new to this..

Comment: If you are doing a homework assignment, you'll learn more from doing it yourself than from me doing it for you.